# How to encode a source string given a reference string

Tags: string, algorithm, encoding

Let's say that we have some reference string that contains all the characters that we need to encode a source string. Given the two strings, the expected output is a list of index ranges that represent the source string using indexes from the reference string. For example:

refString = "abc123abcd"
srcString = "ab123"

valid output 1: [0,2), [3,6)
valid output 2: [6,8), [3,6)

The end index is exclusive, hence the `)`

I can think of a brute force solution where we try every combination of ref indexes for each character in srcString. Then merging all overlapping ranges to get a minimal solution. If we define `n = length(srcString)` and `k = length(refString)`, then we would have to consider `k^n` possible solutions

Is there a more efficient way of solving this problem? Perhaps using a prefix tree?

Comment: The brute force method is to look for the longest match in the `refString`. Then output the range for the match, remove the matching substring from the source, and repeat. In your example, `ab` is matched twice, and `ab1` has no match. So output either `[0,2)` or `[6,8)`, remove `ab`, and search for `123`. To improve performance, use one of the many [string search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Single-pattern_algorithms). You'll need to modify the algorithm to keep track of the start and length of the best match.